# Hibernate Criteria many to many same object

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a User entity that is linked to itself with many to many relation. Basically every User can be a parent or a child and I would like to create a criteria object in order to allow pagination and other filtering. 
In the user I keep reference for both a list of its parents and a list of its children, so the middle table created will have two entries for every user couple.
Basically I do that for being able to have bidirectional relation.

My current Criteria object is:

```
Criteria c = getSession().createCriteria(User.class)
                 .createAlias("parents", "p")
                 .add(Restrictions.eq("p.id", this.getId()))
                 .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

and then I apply the filtering on that criteria.

But this query will only return a list of all the children that has this user as a parent.
I would like to get both the parent and the children.
for example the desired response would be something like this:

> {
>       next:XXX,
>       previous{xxx},
>       data[
>          {parentuser},
>          {child1},
>          {child2}
>          ....
>       ]
>     }

is that possible with criteria?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the simplest solution was to just add the parent as a child to himself since this is a many to many relation this worked fine.
Not a clean solution but it works as expected.